# Two dimensional array of linked list

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I'm trying to create a two dimensional linked list to hold a sparse matrix and have written this code to insert a new node at the right place:

```
void insertNewNode(node **rowHead, node **columnHead, int value, int row, int column) { 
    //Get to the correct position in the column linked list
    if (*columnHead == NULL) {
        *columnHead = malloc(sizeof(node));
    } else {
        while((*columnHead)->nextColumn != NULL && (*columnHead)->nextColumn->row < row)
            *columnHead = (*columnHead)->nextColumn;
    }

    //Get to the correct position in the row linked list.
    if (*rowHead == NULL) {
        *rowHead = malloc(sizeof(node));
    } else {
        while((*rowHead)->nextRow != NULL && ((*rowHead)->nextRow->column < column))
            *rowHead = (*rowHead)->nextRow;
    }

    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->column = column;
    newNode->row = row;
    newNode->value = value;

    (*columnHead)->nextColumn = newNode;
    (*rowHead)->nextRow = newNode;
}
```

For some reason the last line:

```
(*rowHead)->nextRow = newNode;
```

is causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while the previous line is not, and I'm not entirely sure why. Can anyone see a reason why this would occur?

Comment: Where's your `typedef` for node?

Comment: typedef struct node {
    int value, row, column;
    struct node *nextColumn;
    struct node *nextRow;
} node;

Comment: Are you testing malloc for NULL  ??? (during debugging or so?)

Comment: And how are you testing this?

Comment: I'm calling it with insertNewNode(&matrix->rowArray[row], &matrix->columnArray[column], value, row, column); Where rowArray/columnArray in the matrix struct are of type node**

Comment: Did you initialize *heads with NULL ?

Comment: Too few info, we can't know the problem.

Comment: Please post your testing code in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Also:  I have a sneaking suspicion that you should initialize your own placeholders for when you iterate through these linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could just be a problem somewhere else in your program with how your row data is allocated/maintained, and your column data happens to be OK. Have you inspected the value of rowHead? Maybe it is null or a garbage value... then you can trace back from there to figure out how that is happening.